# SSDT Project Publish fails on unicode in PostDeploy - any workarounds or configurations to fix this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, unicode, sql-server-data-tools

We're using SSDT to publish changes to an SQL Server 2005 instance.  We codegen a PostDeploy SQL file that handles updating all of our static data, and it works very well... but only if I execute the PostDeploy script *manually*.  If I let SSDT push it out as an actual Publish/PostDeploy operation, it fails miserably because it garbles all non-ASCII characters.

For example

```
INSERT INTO ##RawData ([FieldID], [FormPageID], [Name], [IsVisible], [DataTypeID], [LookupID], [MaxLength], [DecimalPlaces], [RequiredTypeID], [QuestionLeader], [Text_En], [AdditionalText_En], [StatsVariable], [AdditionalStatsVariable1], [AdditionalStatsVariable2], [StatsDescription], [ApplicabilityLogic], [FieldValueLogic], [Text_Sp], [AdditionalText_Sp]) VALUES (N'92', N'7', N'OtherHeartDisease', N'1', N'2', N'921', N'1', NULL, N'1', N'D.17', N'Have you ever been told you have any other heart disease? ', N'What other heart disease? ', N'svohd', NULL, NULL, N'D17. Other heart disease', NULL, NULL, N'¿Le han dicho alguna vez si tiene alguna otra enfermedad cardiaca?', N'¿Qué otra enfermedad cardiaca?')
```

Becomes

```
INSERT INTO ##RawData ([FieldID], [FormPageID], [Name], [IsVisible], [DataTypeID], [LookupID], [MaxLength], [DecimalPlaces], [RequiredTypeID], [QuestionLeader], [Text_En], [AdditionalText_En], [StatsVariable], [AdditionalStatsVariable1], [AdditionalStatsVariable2], [StatsDescription], [ApplicabilityLogic], [FieldValueLogic], [Text_Sp], [AdditionalText_Sp]) VALUES (N'92', N'7', N'OtherHeartDisease', N'1', N'2', N'921', N'1', NULL, N'1', N'D.17', N'Have you ever been told you have any other heart disease? ', N'What other heart disease? ', N'svohd', NULL, NULL, N'D17. Other heart disease', NULL, NULL, N'�Le han dicho alguna vez si tiene alguna otra enfermedad cardiaca?', N'�Qu� otra enfermedad cardiaca?')
```

And this is what actually appears in the database - ¿Qué becomes �Qu� or ?Qu? or something like that.  Is this a complete limitation of the SSDT tool or is there some obscure config or workaround that I'm unaware-of?  I'm trying to reduce the number of hand-scripted steps in deployment process to as low as possible to keep the headaches off my developers, so getting rid of "publish then execute the data-script" would be a big help.

The database is set with collation sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as but these are NVARCHAR columns so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Got it!

The workaround was to encode the PostDeploy file as UTF-16 (code page 1200).  Apparently SSDT fails hard on SQL scripts encoded in UTF-8.  A lot of MS tools fail on UTF-8, so no surprise there.

Comment: how did you change the encoding of the file? I can't see anything in the properties window in Visual Studio to do this! **UPDATE:** found it.. You can't do it within the project, you have to do it in on disk / in source control.